# WPF Style from code behind is not applying

Tags: wpf

I have to create a separator control upon clicking a button in our application.
The style should be from the resource dictionary.

So it goes like this:

```
        var separator = new Separator();
        try
        {

            separator.Style =  (Style)TryFindResource("columnseperatorStyle");
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

The problem is it does not render in the runtime, I have checked the properties, the style applied it to the separator.

Can someone shed a light?

*Additional Infos

This is how i define the Style which is located in a separate Resource dictionary.

```
<Style x:Key="columnseperatorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}"> 
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

I found out that no problem in retrieving the style. My temporary solution is to retrieve the style in a separate instance of the object. See below

```
 separator = new Separator();
 separator.Style =  (Style)TryFindResource("columnseperatorStyle");

                /*Applying styles to the separator object like below:

                    var separator = new Separator()
                    {
                        Style =  (Style)TryFindResource("columnseperatorStyle");
                    }

                   Does not render the style in the runtime, i don't know why?.
                 */             
                separator = new Separator()
                {
                    Name = colName,
                    Background = separator.Background,
                    Width = separator.Width,
                    HorizontalAlignment = separator.HorizontalAlignment
                };

            grdData.Children.Add(separator);
```

I want to know why the style does not render in runtime using direct assignment of style:

```
        separator.Style =  (Style)TryFindResource("columnseperatorStyle");
```

*New Update

I ended up using line control. :)) there is something with separator control.. that it don't directly apply style.

```
 if (line == null)
        {
            line = new Line()
            {
                Name = colName,
                Style = (Style)TryFindResource("columnLineStyle")
            };

            var relativePoint =     btn.TransformToAncestor(grdData).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
            line.Margin = new Thickness(relativePoint.X + 3, 0, 0, 0);

            grdData.Children.Add(line);
        }
        else
        {
            grdData.Children.Remove(line);
        }
```

Comment: Actually adding `Style` by `TryFindResource` is working well for me. Can you give us more details: How and where you defined your style? Does your separator show up well without applying the style?

Comment: You are actually adding the Separator to the parent control's children list with `AddChild()`, right?

Comment: Please add more information about what you do with the separator after creating it, where / how the style is defined and where the code in question is located. Anyway, you already made my day (in a positive way): Edison is asking people to *"shed a light"* on things?

Comment: hi thank you for reading my concern :) i have added information. 

@bob  , yes it shows up well.

Comment: The code  in the question replaces the separator created on line 1 with the one created on line 13. Are you sure that the code fragment is the actual code you are using?

Comment: line 13-19 is only a temporary solution.. I'm planning to remove it:) i want to apply the style with this line
  separator.Style =  (Style)TryFindResource("columnseperatorStyle");

but unfortunately does not render on runtime

Comment: You should definitely rework your example in a way that it only contains one `new Separator` statement instead of two.

Comment: i agree grek40, i ended up using line control :)) see the new update